# Moving MultiBit wallet to new computer

Tags: multibit

I have a MultiBit wallet and I need to transfer it to a new computer.  I'm not 100% sure which files/ directories need to be transferred.

I've done some reading but the discussion of private keys etc made things more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You should only transfer the `.wallet` file. This already includes the private key and therefor should NEVER be saved unencrypted in a server you do not control, or in a place which is not safe. You can import the `.wallet` file on your other computer and do your bitcoin thingies from there. Make sure to not run both wallets at the same time.

In the main folder of Multibit this `.wallet` file is stored. There is also an `Wallet-data` folder. In there there are several backups of the wallet, and the private key. You can also export this private key, and import it on the other computer. In that way, the wallet will be generated (and will hold exactly the same amount of BTC after synchronising) and you can also do everything you want. Maybe that is what confused you.